# What is the preferred plural form of "bus"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, orthography, doubled-consonants

[image: Busses, or perhaps buses]

The OED states that both "buses" and "busses" are acceptable plural forms of "bus". Is one generally preferred over the other?

Comment: Beware: *busses* could be the plural of *buss* rather than *bus*.  If you don't know, *buss* means *kiss*.

Comment: Or the present tense (3rd person) of to bus.

Comment: ["The Motor Bus"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Motor_Bus) may have something to say on the matter.

Comment: Related: [Plural of 'yes'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168675)

Comment: @GEdgar The usage of *buss* as "to kiss" is essentially archaic today; nobody uses the word in that manner.

Comment: @IanKemp: Nobody? In the OED, *buss*, meaning "A kiss, esp. a loud or vigorous one",  is listed not only as "archaic", but also as "regional (Yorkshire)".  Another meaning of *buss* is a North Sea fishing boat.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To be more precise, the citations in the OED’s entry for *bus* include 2 instances of *busses* and 9 of *buses*. In its own commentary, the OED uses *buses*. The British National Corpus records 1438 instances of *buses* and 10 of *busses*. The figures in the Corpus of Contemporary American English are 5139 and 116. I think that means you’re in good company if you use *buses*.

Answer (score 18):

As others have pointed out, *buses* is far more common than *busses*.

But I see no mention of the fact that in recent decades, *busses* is [almost exclusively restricted](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22busses%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1971,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) to the computer hardware context, where a [bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_%28computer%29) is a *subsystem that transfers data between components inside a computer*. For reasons that escape me, *buses* rarely occurs in the computer context.

EDIT: I'll just add that I worked for decades on computerised systems within the UK public transport industry. Until this question came up I don't think it ever occurred to me that anyone might switch or merge what I'd always thought of as two completely distinct words. But I did sometimes wonder why the computer singular wasn't *always* spelled **buss** (as sometimes it was).

Comment: I think the name of both the vehicle and the electronic interconnect are derived from "omnibus"; the electronic term relates more strongly to "omnibus" than to the vehicle.

Comment: @supercat: The full OED has its first cite for ***omnibus*** as 1828. The first ***buss*** [sic] is only 4 years later. Then there's apostrophized ***'bus*** in 1845, followed by ***busses*** in 1851. They don't have plain ***bus*** until 1887. When it comes to the electronics use, they've got ***buss** wires* in 1887 and *copper '**bus**' bars* in 1888 - under their one-word entry ***busbar***, where OED specifically say ***compare slightly later omnibus bar***.

Answer (score 9):

[Google NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buses,%20busses&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that ***buses*** is more popular than ***busses***.

[image]

Comment: For those concerned about Napoleonic bus stations: *busses* also meant kisses.

Answer (score 6):

You will find *buses* is more popular than *busses*.  Similarly, *omnibuses* was more popular than *omnibusses*

Answer (score 3):

[OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bus) and [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bus_1?q=bus) each lists the plural of *bus* as *buses* but adds that *busses* is also used in AmE. This agrees with [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bus) which lists both forms. I would go for *buses* which applies to both variants currently.