# Plural of 'yes'

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, doubled-consonants

What is the plural of yes? Googling brings up many different suggestions from different sources.

- Yesses
- Yeses
- Yes's
- Yes' ?

Comment: [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yes%27s%2Cyeses%2Cyesses&year_start=1980&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyes%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyeses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyesses%3B%2Cc0) suggests yeses

Comment: @billynomates: In what context are you using it? For instance, if it was related to some kind of vote then wouldn't `ayes` be more appropriate?

Comment: Or 'yes votes'...

Comment: "affirmatives" ?

Comment: @James Not necessarily. On the TV show "Britain's got Talent", The phrase "You've got four yeses" is quite common. I can't really imagine that being replaced with "ayes".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yes) gives *yeses* and *yesses* as accepted spellings of the plural of yes, whereas [searching Cambridge Dictionaries Online for *yesses*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/search/british/direct/?q=yesses) does not return any results.

In the absence of agreement amongst widely accepted authorities, it's a good idea to turn to usage. A quick [Google N-gram query for occurrences *yeses* vs. *yesses* in their library of books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yesses,yeses&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,yesses;,c0;.t1;,yeses;,c0) published between 1800 and 2008 suggests that, from the twentieth century onwards, *yeses* has been the preferred to *yesses* (the tool is seemingly unable to parse apostrophes); greatly so from around 1950 onwards.

If I were to use *yes* in its plural form, I would therefore opt for *yeses*. Given that there is no authoritative consensus, though, it is to a large extent a matter of preference. I imagine there is no fixed, definitive spelling because (anecdotally) it doesn't seem to be a word that is commonly used in the plural, an observation that the N-Gram results appear to support.

Comment: If it could parse apostrophes better, it would most likely find the form *yes's* to have been more common at the beginning of that time, and to have declined since.

Comment: It can handle apostrophes now, yeses wins by far: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yesses%2Cyeses%2Cyes%27s%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyeses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyes%20%27s%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 7):

Any of the first three. An argument could be made for the fourth. I'd advise that you favour the second, or perhaps the third depending on your dialect. (The OED incidentally offers *yes's* and *yeses*, while some other dictionaries offer *yesses* as well).

The noun *yes* comes from a mention of the much older adjective *yes*.

Now, how plural forms apply to mention (as in the use/mention distinction) has been discussed elsewhere here, but two common forms are:

1. Use an apostrophe in forming the plural.
2. Pluralise it as you would any other word.

(Some other forms include italicising the *yes* but not the *es*, and putting the *yes* part in single or double quotes).

The first is increasingly old-fashioned and sometimes mistaken for "grocer's apostrophe's" where people incorrectly use apostrophes with normal plural forms, but it was once the normal way of pluralising in such contexts (see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104235/15770) for more on that).

As such, while historically valid, it's probably best avoided.

Now, from the second we would expect *yeses*, because that's the normal productive plural form for a word ending in *-es*.

Meanwhile, doubling the *s* in this case is rare but not unheard of (c.f. both *buses* and *busses* are found, the latter according the the OED being more common in America). Hence *yesses* also being found.

The last though would be very strange; it half-uses the old form, but in the old form the apostrophe acts as a separator and there is nothing on the other side of the separator.

As such, I'd reject the last, accept the first as valid, but recommend you use either *yeses* or *yesses* depending on whether the orthography you normally use has you write *buses* or *busses*.

Answer (score 1):

The New Oxford American Dictionary says that the plural of *yes* is *yeses* or *yesses*.